# What is the purpose of public, protection, private on class diagram? Any examples?

Tags: java, php, private, public, protected

I've been curious about access modifiers.

**public** means that the item is available to anyone who has access to the object,

**protected** means that it's available to the object itself and any subclasses, and

**private** means it can be accessed only within the class itself.

But, I don't know the example of public, protected, and private use cases.
I mean, could anyone please explain me the cases about public, private and protected access modifiers on class diagram?
Just to make sure that I'm understand them right.

Thanks!

Comment: What do these (Java) access types have to do with MySQL or databases?

Comment: databases @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

Exactly there is not only 3 access types, in different languages there is more of them.
For example:

1. **public** – class or its members defined with this access modifier will be publicly accessible from anywhere, even from outside the scope of the class.
2. **private** – class members with this keyword will be accessed within the class itself. It protects members from outside class access with the reference of the class instance.
3. **protected** – same as private, except by allowing subclasses to access protected superclass members.
4. **abstract** – This keyword can be used only for PHP classes and its functions. For containing abstract functions, a PHP class should be an abstract class.
5. **final** – It prevents subclasses to override super class members defined with final keyword.
6. **internal** - can access within the program that contain its declarations and also access within the same assembly level but not from another assembly.
7. **protected internal** - same access levels of both protected and internal. It can access anywhere in the same assembly and in the same class also the classes inherited from the same class

Some of them is applicable to classes, some to functions and other to variables also.
So, in most languages all class members is declared with **public** access type (except Java, for example).

Returning to the main question.
Application of all this access modifiers is to facilitate the encapsulation of components.

Simple example of use of such access modifiers in C++ ([taken from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct B { // default access modifier inside struct is public
    void set_n(int v) { n = v; }
    void f()          { cout << "B::f" << endl; }
  protected:
    int m, n; // B::m, B::n are protected
  private:
    int x;
};

struct D : B {
    using B::m;               // D::m is public
    int get_n() { return n; } // B::n is accessible here, but not outside
//  int get_x() { return x; } // ERROR, B::x is inaccessible here
 private:
    using B::f;               // D::f is private
};

int main() {
    D d;

//  d.x = 2; // ERROR, private
//  d.n = 2; // ERROR, protected
    d.m = 2; // protected B::m is accessible as D::m

    d.set_n(2); // calls B::set_n(int)
    cout << d.get_n() << endl; // output: 2

//  d.f();   // ERROR, B::f is inaccessible as D::f


    B& b = d; // b references d and "views" it as being type B

//  b.x = 3; // ERROR, private
//  b.n = 3; // ERROR, protected
//  b.m = 3; // ERROR, B::m is protected

    b.set_n(3); // calls B::set_n(int)
//  cout << b.get_n(); // ERROR, 'struct B' has no member named 'get_n'

    b.f();   // calls B::f()
    return 0;
}
```

So, to understand the purpose of this modifiers, firstly you must understand the core principals of Object Oriented Programming, and especially the encapsulation paradigm.
This is not something that can be easily explained with peace of example code.
Modifiers is very little part of huge OOP world.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you use the Public, private, protected and other access modifiers keyword to control access to class members.
For example, you want a variable or a method to be used for internal purposes only inside the class, but that member should never been seen outside from the class, then you should declare it with "Private" access modifier keyword.

On the other hand "Public" is used to declare members that should be accessed from outside the class, constructors are clear example of why you should declare them with "Public" keyword. Other members such as methods which perform useful task like (.ToString, .Substring) are also great examples of members that should be declared as public, in short they can be used from outside the class and perform useful tasks to anyone who use your class.

Consider this:

```
class employee
{
private int instanceCount = 0;
private string empName;

public employee(string fname, string lname)
{
//Provide some code for the constructor.
empname = fname + " " + lname;
instanceCount ++;}
}
```

It's clear that the constructor should be public and "instanceCount" variable that is used to count the number of instances is private.

For protected, everything that applies to private applies also to protected, with a small difference, protected can be used by inheriting classes, private not.